Dynamic RAM allocation with node.js
I have a node.js application being managed by pm2, the application allocates dynamic memory by default and is limited to using as little memory as possible and using memory if necessary. However, this process is making the system slow and heavy when there are many users, my idea would be to force the application to use its maximum potential or close to it. I have a vps hosted on hostinger km8, very robust with 32 gb of ram but the system uses 3% of memory and reaches 4% cpu usage.
Does anyone have any idea what is going on or have had a similar experience?
I tried using node --max-old-space-size= to increase the memory limit but it wasn't enough to increase usage and only increased the limit, I haven't tried to disable swap yet because my application is already in production. would it be a good idea?
